# How to add a RSS Feed to a solr search view in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views, search, feeds

I'm trying to add a rss feed to my website.
It has content indexed by a a solr search and somehow when I try to add a RSS feed it says:

> Style RSS Feed requires a row style but the row plugin is invalid.

Also in the edit view the following message is shown:

> Show: Missing style plugin

using drupal 7, solr, and views

Using a 'normal' view RSS 'page' can be created

How do I add the missing style plugin and where do I find this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a temporary solution I created a new view with the same content added a rss feed to that. now I do have a rss feed but not on the page I want it to be.

I'll accept this answer until a better one shows up.